# Media Queries para Java Script - Qual o erro nesta sintaxe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, media-queries

Essa é a primeira vez que tento aplicar uma regra de media queries em java script e, como sou iniciante, acredito que algo nesta sintaxe esteja errado, já que a única função que está funcionando é a segunda (com visible: 3) e em todos os viewports.

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 768px)');
if (mq.matches) {
    $("#carrossel").jCarouselLite({
        btnPrev: ".anterior"
        , btnNext: ".proximo"
        , visible: 1
        , auto: 2000
        , speed: 1000
    });

} else {
    $("#carrossel").jCarouselLite({
        btnPrev: ".anterior"
        , btnNext: ".proximo"
        , visible: 3
        , auto: 2000
        , speed: 1000
    });
}
```

Comment: Will, você copiou isso da documentação do jCarousel ou fez por si próprio?

O que era pra ocorrer ai até então é exibir uma imagem para todas as larguras inferiores a 768px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O constragimento é originado na1ª linha

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 768px)');
```

deverá ser assim.:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
```

Fonte.:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Muito obrigado, Tiago! Resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Creio que se remover o `@media all and` irá funcionar.

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');
if (mq.matches) {
  console.log('menor');

} else {
 console.log('maior');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo funcional no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr6xprfh/1/).

Outra opção seria usar o [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) do jQuery.

```js
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  alert('menor');

} else {
  alert('maior');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr6xprfh/2/).